# error of floating point exception(core dumped)

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

```
global _start
section .data
    var dq 12494F04A6344129h    
    msg db "The number of times 4 present in the given number"
    len equ $-msg 
    novar db 00
section .bss

section .text
    mov dl,0Ah
    mov cl,10

_start  :
    mov rsi,var
    up: mov al,byte ptr [rsi]
        mov ah,00
        div dl
        cmp ah,04
        je dn
        jne dn1
    dn: inc byte[novar]
    dn1:    inc rsi
        dec cl
        jne up
        jmp exit

exit:   mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg
    mov edx,len
    int 80h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,novar
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

Comment: Can you provide more context on where and how this occurred?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? Nnote that you don't need `jmp exit` if `exit` is the label on the very next instruction. Don't you need `mov edx, [len]` not `mov edx, len`? Do you want `edx` to be the value stored at `len` or the value of `len` itself (the address of the label)?

Answer (score 1):

Nasm doesn't use "ptr" - that won't even assemble.

The first two lines - above the `_start:` label - are never executed, so those registers are never initialized. That's probably what causes the exception. `dl` is probably zero!

`len` is fine - it's an equate, not a variable.

You probably want to add the character `'0'` to `novar` before printing it.

None of this looks useful to me. Are you sure this is the question you're trying to answer, @Shubham Satpute?